# Git commit message not taking to the next step

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I use vim (basic functions to write code..) but this keeps returning different performance when I use those shortcuts I'm familiar with. This hasn't happened once either.. embarrassed to encounter these issues and not know how to resolve; but Id really like to understand first.
[image]

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? What are you trying to do and what is stopping you?

Comment: I just wanted to write a comment and finish the `commit` command. Instead some shortcuts were interpreted to rearrange the texts and now  I cannot get out of this window by 'ESC' + 'wq!' or 'q!' How did it even enter debugger..?

Comment: This looks like you've invoked an editor other than vim, probably some variant of emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first your `git config core.editor` value.

If it is *not* vim (but instead emacs or nano or ...), that would explain the strange Lisp error message you see.
That looks like an error message you would see with [Magit for instance](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/772).

`git config --global core.editor "vim"` should be enough for you to try again, with the vim editor.